# Limesurvey conditional based on survey id

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, limesurvey

Hi i need to add a static link on Limesurvey navigation.
we have multiple surveys and i want to add link only for a single survey.

How can i add that (based on survey id for example)

```
<!-- startpage.pstl -->
......................
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand col-xs-8" href="#">{SURVEYNAME}</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {SAVE_LINKS}
            {CLEARALL_LINKS}
            {QUESTION_INDEX_MENU}
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- Top container -->
    <div id="topContainer" class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            {PERCENTCOMPLETE}
            {LANGUAGECHANGER}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="outerframe container" id="outerframeContainer">

        <div class="row" id="main-row">

            <div class='col-xs-12' id="yii-flash-message">
                {FLASHMESSAGE}
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-centered" id="main-col">
<!-- end of startpage.pstl -->
```

Please help.

I basically need a  tag between {CLEARALL_LINKS} and 
                {QUESTION_INDEX_MENU}  (only for a particular survey id)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SID placeholder in an Expression Manager IF() statement.

```
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand col-xs-8" href="#">{SURVEYNAME}</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {SAVE_LINKS}
        {CLEARALL_LINKS}
        {if(SID == 123456, '<li><a href="http://example.com">Conditional link</a></li>', '')}
        {QUESTION_INDEX_MENU}
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you made my day !